# Maven dependencies. Change the parent's lib version

Tags: java, maven

My current project consists of the parent pom file and couple of dependent projects.
In the parent's pom I specify this libraries from the spring:

```
<properties>
 <spring.framework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

There is on project A which contains all basic classes for others and included in every submodule. I use the spring version which  is defined in the parent's POM.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the project B i have a reference to the project A, but i want to use  3.1.O.RELEASE of this libraries.

I've tried to exclude those libraries and put the specific versions in the project's B pom file but it didn't worked. I still have the 3.2.4.RELEASE version.

Any ideas how can i solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: So after you exclude those libraries, can you run a mvn dependency:tree on project B and see who is transitively bringing the 3.2.4.Release version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just precise your libraries versions explicitly in your POM for project B:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.O.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.O.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It will override any transitive dependency version.
Be sure to precise all Spring artifacts as there are a lot. Best way would be to include all Spring deps in dependencyManagement in parent using spring.framework.version property. Then override this property to the correct version in project B:

```
<properties>
    <spring.framework.version>3.1.O.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: note that if you need *exactly* some version, this is not enough,  you should use `<version>[3.1.O.RELEASE]</version>`. See for example [dependency version ranges](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) for details.

Comment: Actually it worked but with small fixes. I had to put all transitive dependencies inside the pom (like spring-beans ,spring-core etc.)